# Can I use property name of object as parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make Favorite module in my app. I'm using React-native and Firestore. Here is my code:

```
addFavorite() {
    getPlaceName().doc(this.selectedPlaceName.id).set({
        favorite: {
           uid : true
        }
    }, { merge: true }).then(() => {
        console.log('Added')
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log('error', e)
    })
}
removeFavorite() {
    getPlaceName().doc(this.selectedPlaceName.id).set({
        favorite: {
            uid: false
        }
    }, { merge: true }).then(() => {
        console.log('Removed')
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log('error', e)
    })
}
```

I store Favorite as a map in Firestore:

```
favorite: {
    u001: true,
    u002: false}
```

So are there any ways to achieve it? Or do you guys have any other ideas how to get this favorite thing done?

Comment: What is not working for you and what are you expecting from community? Please describe about the issue

Comment: I have "u001" or "u002" as my example user Id. But how can I pass in my function?

Comment: Pass to Which function? Your query is not clear.

Comment: I have two functions "addFavorite" and "removeFavorite" to change specific user id to true or false. To achieve that I need to pass the user id into the two functions above, that uid: true/false, by uid value might be "u001" or "u002" depending on which user is logging in.

Answer (score 1):

The following code, using [square brackets notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), should work (if I understand correctly your question!):

```
addFavorite(uid) {
    const favoriteObj = {}
    favoriteObj[uid]  = true;
    getPlaceName().doc(this.selectedPlaceName.id).set({
        favorite: favoriteObj
    }, { merge: true }).then(() => {
        console.log('Added')
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log('error', e)
    })
}
removeFavorite(uid) {
    const favoriteObj = {}
    favoriteObj[uid]  = false;
    getPlaceName().doc(this.selectedPlaceName.id).set({
        favorite: favoriteObj
    }, { merge: true }).then(() => {
        console.log('Removed')
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log('error', e)
    })
}
```

**Update:**
Since a lot of code is common between your two functions, note that you could re-factorize your code in one function, like:

```
setFavorite(uid, isFavorite) {
    const favoriteObj = {}
    favoriteObj[uid]  = isFavorite;
    getPlaceName().doc(this.selectedPlaceName.id).set({
        favorite: favoriteObj
    }, { merge: true }).then(() => {
        if (isFavorite) {
           console.log('Added')
        } else {
           console.log('Removed')
        }
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log('error', e)
    })
}
```

where `isFavorite` is a boolean. You could call it like, for example:

```
setFavorite("u001", true);
```

or

```
setFavorite("u002", false);
```

Comment: That works perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, see the update to my answer.